# Why HttpClient testing doesn't require done() function?

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular4-httpclient

it's simple example from the official documentation.
https://angular.io/guide/http#expecting-and-answering-requests

```js
it('can test HttpClient.get', () => {
  const testData: Data = {name: 'Test Data'};

  // Make an HTTP GET request
  httpClient.get<Data>(testUrl)
    .subscribe(data =>
      // When observable resolves, result should match test data
      expect(data).toEqual(testData)
    );

  // The following `expectOne()` will match the request's URL.
  // If no requests or multiple requests matched that URL
  // `expectOne()` would throw.
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('/data'); 

  // Assert that the request is a GET.
  expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  // Respond with mock data, causing Observable to resolve.
  // Subscribe callback asserts that correct data was returned.
  req.flush(testData);

  // Finally, assert that there are no outstanding requests.
  httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

And I don't understand here why they don't use `done` function from Jasmine here. In my opinion it's async operation, it should be tested with `done` callback. But at the same time everything seems work, so it's really magic for me.

Comment: Don't ever recalled `HttpClient` have `done()` function other than `on complete` callback. See [RxJS api on Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) no such function defined as `done()`.

Comment: you want to say "do"?

Comment: `done` is part of Jasmine framework for async testing https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.0/global.html#implementationCallback

Comment: Not sure what jasmine have to do with `Observable`, if `Observable` doesn't implement `done()` function how would you expect to call `done()`? Should read more on how `RxJS` / `HttpClient` works.

Comment: If you want to make asynchronous calls within Jasmine, you have several operators, such as, for instance, `async` from `@angular/core/testing`. The only time I use the callback (`done`), is when I use a Timeout to make expectations. My guess is that unless you trigger the change detection, you don't need to call the callback function, you can just run a test without it.

Comment: it doesn't relate to Observable at all. Jasmine can handle any async operations in test (and Observables are async too). Here some code examples from older doc version https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: @trichetriche is some cases it leads to fake test results, because by default test without any expectation is positive test. So, you test nothing even you have `expect` in your callback.

Comment: What do you want us to say, if it leads to fake results, then use the callback !

Comment: @trichetriche but this code is from official documentation! and it really tests! That's my problem, you can play with it here https://stackblitz.com/angular/egpodepgoxn?file=src%2Ftesting%2Fhttp-client.spec.ts

Answer (score 1):

ok, I'll try to answer my own question after checking how MockBackend works, some reading and some experiments.

Upon `.get()` the mock backend creates a new request and push it in the inner array, your observer function is part of of this request. The `.expectOne()` method extracts this request from array and return to the test. `.flush()` feeds observer with provided data and complete it. So, with some assumption, code above can be rewritten in next way

```
it('should work with observables', () => {
  const sub = new Subject();

  sub.subscribe((value) => {
    expect(value).toBe('a');
    // un-comment this line to see that this code really executes, 
    // test will fail
    // expect(1).toBe(2);
  });

  sub.next('a');
});
```

So, basically we have here a chain of nested callbacks, don't call any of WebAPIs and work on the same observable: `.handle()` method of the backend creates it and `.flush()` calls the `.next()` on it.

That's why don't need `done()` function from jasmine here.